# Where can one learn about viewership ratings for anime?

Tags: anime-production, resources

In the U.S., companies like [Nielsen](http://www.nielsen.com/us/en/top10s.html) track viewership of television programs. What is the equivalent of this for Japanese television programs (and, in particular, anime), if any?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest thing you can probably find to something like Nielsen is [Video Research](http://www.videor.co.jp/data/ratedata/top10.htm#anime). It's in Japanese (of course) but google translate does pretty well with the anime titles.

Also, there is [this site](http://www.geocities.jp/animesityouritu/) which lists historical ratings that go back to 2000.

As for anime movies, DVD/BD rankings, there's [Oricon](http://www.oricon.co.jp/rank/).