# Is there an official site for anime and manga ranking?

Tags: resources

Is there any official site for anime and manga ranking? I know some site for anime and manga, and they have some kind of rating and ranking, but their rating and ranking are different. I'm wondering if there are any official site for anime, maybe something like IMDB? Honestly, I don't really know if IMDB is official or not, but if someone is to ask for the rating of a movie, they always say to look it in IMDB.

Comment: Official by what measure?

Comment: anime news network

Comment: what are the parameters which you would focus in the anime?

Comment: also aren't ratings on a lot of sites (as far as I know anyway) generated by user votes? would such sites still be "official"?

Comment: I think the OP is asking for the ratings per magazine. For example, the Beelzebub's ranking on Weekly Shounen Jump has been around 18 for the past few weeks. As for a website that has all the magazines' official ratings for each individual series, I can't think of one off the top of my head.

Comment: Rank them according to what? Popularity? Sales? Reviews?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know there is no official ranking site for anime/manga.

The closest thing you could get to an official ranking would be ranking them according to their sales, which gets featured on a lot of sites. An example would be this [MyAnimeList post](http://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=759719). More info and sites can be found on the post [Where can one learn about viewership ratings for anime?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/5095/1458), where some nice sites have been listed.

Most other rating sites are, as [hungerartist](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/2604/hungerartist) mentioned, user rated and therefore not official.

Comment: Don't bother with MAL lists, this is way more useful: [Cumulative DVD/Blu-ray sales](http://forums.animesuki.com/showthread.php?t=109699)

Comment: @Uriziel The MAL lists are useful if you want data collated by what was popular during a given week; the AnimeSuki lists are useful for a longer historical perspective. They both have their uses, and they both use Oricon data. The MAL lists also have Oricon data for manga/LNs/audio. Does Animesuki have an analog of that?

Answer (score 6):

**OP please read this, I took the time to write it for you**

I write this hoping to rid you of some misconceptions you seem to have. Even though it's been almost 2 years, I took the time to help you.

Very few things can/should get an official rating or ranking. Art, like movies and anime, definitely SHOULD NOT! (or cannot, depending how you see it)

**The rating in IMDB is the average of the scores given by random people who took the time to rate in that site. The same could be said of most movie/TV/anime sites that have ratings.**
IMDB is such a big reference because it has a gigantic amount of users who rate. And that's why it is a good reference and people point you to it. But it isn't an official rating site and it cannot be one.

People are not forced to rate, so any rating you see anywhere is either by a single person or a selection of people. In sites like IMDB that selection is people who have watched that piece, out of everyone in the world, who also:

1. Know of and use that site,
2. Take the time to rate (publicly),
3. Happen to have rated that particular piece.

So ratings/scores are a reference, and you should use them keeping in mind who gave them.

If a website has become the *de facto* "go to place" for rates/ranks, like IMDB has for movies, then it's a very valuable reference, but not an official consensus of the viewers.

The only numbers you can get that may be "official" are stuff like manga or DVD sales (factual numbers).

**For anime, the website that seems to be the big reference in ratings is [MyAnimeList](http://myanimelist.net/) (MAL).**

My only problem with it is it has no input from Japanese viewers, since (probably) almost no Japanese use it. You only get the input of avid western watchers, and Japanese viewers obviously have a very different context. (I'm looking for a Japanese equivalent to MAL for an extra reference, which was why I found your post).

I recommend you use MAL: not only to see ratings and other information, but to make a list for yourself, even if you normally don't care about doing your own lists and ratings. You can use the list to keep track of what you're watching/have watched, which episode you're on, etc. You can have your own ratings of anime for future reference (influencing the average score by doing so). It's super useful, really, otherwise I wouldn't give them this free publicity.

Hope this wasn't a total waste. All the best.

Comment: Welcome to the Anime/Manga SE. If you're interested enough, you could ask a new question on Japanese equivalents to sites like MAL (under the `resources` tag). Incidentally, another danger of ratings sites is the possibility that people are rating things carelessly or using criteria that are not going to be relevant, although I've only seen this happen in a few isolated cases with book reviews (in one case, for a book that I would not have rated highly anyway).

Comment: If you want a Japanese website like MAL, you may want to visit [Anikore](https://www.anikore.jp/pop_ranking/), but be aware that the ranking calculation is completely different compared to MAL. First, users give a rating out of 5 on story, animation, voice acting, music, and characters, then an average is calculated to get a global rating out of 5. Additionally, each anime rank score is calculated using an unknown formula which accounts for total number of favorites, number of votes on tags, number of reviews, user ratings, number of tweets, and calculated credibility score of users.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's nothing official, as there's nothing official that regulates anime industry or something. You can try Dimitri's solution, but I would recommend sticking to Anime News Network and looking at their sales reports instead of seeing what's popular.

Sales charts are more useful, popularity often has a multiplier effect.