# Is there a way to know which manga/anime is on in a particular country?

Tags: resources

I'm curious which manga/anime is published/aired in which country and how they are accepted.

**Background**

I feel that manga popularities vary from country to country (or region to region). To mention a few impressions, I feel

1. Outside Japan, Naruto is generally more popular than One Piece. (In Japan, by most measures, I believe One Piece is more popular). [This](https://www.polygon.com/22892059/most-popular-anime-united-states) claims now One Piece is the most popular in the US, but since Naruto is no longer active, I think the popularity of Naruto is rather confirmed by the fact that it still competes with One Piece.
2. An anime/manga like [Doraemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doraemon) is significantly lesser known in Western countries. I've heard it is known in Asian countries. Just to give an idea how well-known it is Japan, meeting a person who has never seen a Ghibli movie would surprise me, but my eyes would pop out if I meet someone who has never seen at least a few episodes of Doraemon (or I would automatically conclude the person did not spend childhood in Japan).

**Questions**

1. Is there a way to know which anime is published in which country, other than manually searching individual title on the web?
2. Is there a way to know the difference of popularity across countries/regions?

Or since people can watch most things online now in some way, the questions does not make much sense?

---

A related question:

- [Is there an official site for anime and manga ranking?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/7240/61507)

I'm looking more for how well-known, not necessarily how popular. (It may be the same thing since unpopularity may lead to an end soon enough abroad.)

Comment: For 1) AFAIK, there's no such site yet, and it's complicated with licensing and geoblocking for anime (ignoring piracy, of course).

Comment: is there maybe a way to filter myanimelist ratings to see like accounts from say the philippines only? or indonesia only?

Comment: @BCLC filtering accounts on MyAnimeList may still not be reliable because they can still watch while on overseas, or from buying DVD/BD, or well... bypassing geoblock.